# Make all references to an object null so it can be collected

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implement behavior similar to that of the `GameObject` in Unity3D.

I have many, many objects in any given application that reference any given number of other objects. Each object can be marked for deletion, and when it is; I need to know how to nullify any references to it so that it can be collected by the GC and literally removed from scope altogether. I'm either looking for a way to fake this or a way of actually doing it.

For all intents and purposes; if an object references another, and the referenced object is destroyed, I need the reference to appear to be null. If I can't do this then my only other option is to check every reference, every time I use them, and manually evaluate whether it's been destroyed, which isn't practical.

Answer (score 3):

There are two approaches that I know of which come close to what you described:

### Approach 1: WeakReference

Only use `WeakReference` to reference to objects except for one '`DataManager`' that retains a hard reference.

You can then 'mark' instances for garbage collection by clearing the hard reference of the `DataManager`.

```
public class DataManager
{
    private readonly HashSet<object> data = new HashSet<object>();


    public void RegisterInstance(object instance)
    {
        data.Add(instance);
    }

    public void FreeInstance(object instance)
    {
        data.Remove(instance)
    }
}


public class Foo
{
    List<WeakReference<Bar>> bars = new List<WeakReference<Bar>>();

    private readonly DataManager dataManager;


    public Foo(DataManager dataManager)
    {
        this.dataManager = dataManager;
    }

    public void LogSomething()
    {
        bars.Add( Bar.Create(dataManager, 3, "Susan"));
        bars.Add( Bar.Create(dataManager, 4, "Bob"));
        bars.Add( Bar.Create(dataManager, 0, "Megan"));

        dataManager.FreeInstance(bars[1]);
        CG.Collect();

        for(int i = bars.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--;)
        {
            // hard reference to not loose the reference target between now and logging
            Bar bar;
            if(!bars[i].TryGetTarget(out bar)
            {
                bars.RemoveAt(i);
                continue;
            }

            Debug.Log($"{bar.value.Data2} has {bar.value.Data1} chocolate bars");
        }
    }
}


public class Bar
{
    public int Data1 { get; private set; }
    public string Data2 { get; private set; }

    private Bar(int data1, string data2)
    {
        Data1 = data1;
        Data2 = data2;
    }

    public static WeakReference<Bar> Create(DataManager dataManager, int data1, string data2)
    {
        var bar = new Bar(data1, data2);
        dataManager.RegisterInstance(bar);
        return new WeakReference(bar);
    }
}
```

**Cons**

- Weak references will continue to point to the target that was marked for deletion until it is actually garbage collected.
- Running the garbage collector after each deletion isn't a very good idea
- It's slow
- Garbage collector might not even collect it. Meaning that a WeakReference can suddenly lose reference between two lines of code some time after deletion. This requires you to keep a hard reference everytime that you have to access the target of a weak reference more than just once.
- You have to register every created object in the `DataManager`.
- It's very easy to forget to use `WeakReference` to reference to objects.

### Approach 2: Use a wrapper

You can wrap all your objects in a generic class and only reference the wrapper, but you have to use the same wrapper for every object of T.
So you will need some kind of `DataManager` like in approach 1.

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Value { get; private set; }


    public Wrapper(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
        if(Value == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Already deleted");
        Value = null;
    }

    public static implicit operator T(Wrapper<T> wrapper) => wrapper.value;
    public static implicit operator Wrapper<T>(T x) => new Wrapper(x);
}


public class Foo
{
    List<Wrapper<Bar>> bars = new List<Wrapper<Bar>>();


    public void LogSomething()
    {
        bars.Add( new Bar(3, "Susan"));
        bars.Add( new Bar(4, "Bob"));
        bars.Add( new Bar(0, "Megan"));

        bars[1].Delete()
        for(int i = bars.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--;)
        {
            var bar = bars[i];
            if(bar.value == null)
            {
                bars.RemoveAt(i);
                continue;
            }

            Debug.Log($"{bar.value.Data2} has {bar.value.Data1} chocolate bars");
        }
    }
}


public class Bar
{
    public int Data1 { get; private set; }
    public string Data2 { get; private set; }

    public Bar(int data1, string data2)
    {
        Data1 = data1;
        Data2 = data2;
    }
}
```

You could also overwrite the `equals` method of `Wrapper` to achieve the following behavior:

```
var bar = new Wrapper<Bar>(null);
var isWrappedValueNull = bar == null;
// overwrite 'equals' if you want isWrappedValueNull to be true in this case
```

*I wrote this with the android app - example code might have minor errors*

Answer (score 0):

You can't set `this` (aka 'yourself') to `null` so that references to you will be lost / destroyed. `this` is read-only.

Something you can do is using events to tell the ones referencing the instance to set it to `null`. Don't forget to unsubscribe the event handler when setting the instance to `null`.

Comment: @user2312610: I am sorry but I am pretty sure this isn't possible in .NET. Can you give a more detailed example?

Comment: @user2312610 Those with years .net excpecience gladly tell you you misinerpret what you see in unity. It is not possible.

Comment: You mean something like [`Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Yes, indeed. The latter is impossible according to the language specs.

Comment: @user2312610: Yeah, that helps if you only reference the outer instance, not the inner instance.

Comment: Well, then to answer tha - a concrete example where you see this behavior please.

Comment: @TomTom: See OP's answer. It's in the C++-wrapper, and it is comparable to the `Dispose` method.

Comment: As I said - he totally misinterpreted what is really going on and thus made bad claims.